# github workflow to push to private repo

Tags: git, github-actions, workflow, git-push

I made this workflow to push changes from my `private` github repo to push it to another `private` repo on another platform

```
name: Push to repo
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    BRANCH:
      description: 'Branch to use'
      required: true
      default: 'production'
      type: choice
      options:
        - production
        - develop
jobs:
  push-to-ccfe:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          ssh-keyscan git.something  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh-agent -a ${{ env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }} > /dev/null
          ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"
          
      - name: setup git and push to remote
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "${{ secrets.GH_MAIL }}"
          git remote add newremote git@git.something
      - name: Check branch and push
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          git fetch origin -a        
          git push newremote ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}:${{ inputs.BRANCH }}
```

it's all good up until I actually try to push

where I first get a warning:

```
warning: no common commits
```

and then the actual error:

```
 ! [rejected]        develop -> develop (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git.something'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I don't understand if I try from the terminal and push I get no errors.

p.s.
the point of this workflow is to avoid using the terminal, I want to put a cronjob so that changes to this repo are pushed in another remote.

Comment: There are some actions on the [github marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=git+commit+push+) that can help you doing this by abstracting the git management complexity for you. Have you try some of them?

Comment: can you link one that would suit this use case?

Comment: Those two action allow to push to a different remote repository: [Git Commit/Push Changes](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-commit-push-changes) and [git commit push action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/git-commit-push-action). The first one has been implemented using a Dockerfile (therefore, is compatible with ubuntu runners only).

Comment: those use access_tokens that I don't have (I have ssh key), plus I am not making any commits, just pushing whatever is new in `branch`

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/push-git-subdirectory-as-branch) could maybe be an option then (informing the whole repo as folder using `.`)

Comment: "No common commits" is a pretty strong hint here. I would bet that it's a case of shallow-clone combined with two-or-more-commits-to-be-added; the shallow clone lacks the linking commits, causing the problem. Try using a non-shallow clone (see the GitHub actions documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently the solution was to change the `checkout` command at the beginning.

this gets me what I needed

```
name: Push to repo
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      BRANCH:
        description: 'Branch to use'
        required: true

jobs:
  push-to-domainXXX:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          ssh-keyscan git.domainXXX  >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          ssh-agent -a ${{ env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK }} > /dev/null
          ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"

      - name: setup git and push to remote
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "${{ secrets.GH_MAIL }}"
          git remote add second_origin git@domainXXX:myusername/repo_name
          
      - name: Check branch and push
        env:
          SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
        run: |
          git push second_origin ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your commands are:

```bash
git remote add origin git@git.something
git fetch origin -a   
git push origin ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}:${{ inputs.BRANCH }}
```

You are fetching and pushing to the same `origin` (same remote repository)

Assuming that the original `checkout` did set `origin`, I would rather set a second remote, for referencing the second remote repository (you want to push to).
Then fetch from the first and push from the second:

```bash
git remote add second git@git.something
git fetch origin -a   
git push second ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}:${{ inputs.BRANCH }}
```

Comment: I think there was a typo in the question... I call the remote in another way like in your answer.

Comment: @bruvio OK. If force pushing (meaning replacing the remote history with the local one) is not an issue: `git push --force second ${{ inputs.BRANCH }}:${{ inputs.BRANCH }}`, to check if the end result is what you want.